# UiPath Studio - Cannot acquire a license

Tags: uipath, uipath-studio, uipath-orchestrator

I installed UiPath Studio from the tutorial.  I assume this is the community edition.  I followed the instructions though they may be a bit dated.  When I attempt to open Studio from my desktop and click "Sign In", I get an error message "Cannot Acquire a License".  I opened the license tab and it appears all necessary licenses are installed such a "attended robot"  Can anyone help?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried connecting via UiPath Assistance ?

Comment: I signed in with UiPath Assistant and was then able to sign into Studio.  Seems to work.  Thanks for your help!